Unable to install scikit learn ver 0.20.0 on Google Colab
For a school project, I'm trying to reproduce a solution from Kaggle competition that was submitted 6 years ago. A lot of the packages are deprecated, and the difference in package versions seem to be causing different output results when running the codes on Google Colab.
There was a specific problem with version of Sci-kit Learn that is being used. The kaggle notebook uses the following version:
0.20.dev0
However, when I tried to "downgrade" the scikit learn package on google colab, I encountered the following issue:
!pip install scikit-learn==0.20.0
Collecting scikit-learn==0.20.0
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.20.0.tar.gz (28.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from scikit-learn==0.20.0) (1.26.4)
Collecting scipy>=0.13.3 (from scikit-learn==0.20.0)
  Using cached scipy-1.13.0-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
Using cached scipy-1.13.0-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (38.2 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-learn
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for scikit-learn (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-learn
  Running setup.py clean for scikit-learn
Failed to build scikit-learn
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-learn, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Is there any way to use a specified old version of Python packages on Google Colab?
I need to maintain the consistency of outputs produced by the models. I set everything else as the same with the original kaggle notebook, including seed and hyperparameters.

Are you using the same version of python?
